# Java Timer: create a new instance from the timer after caneclling the first one without crashing?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I programm a 2D Game in LWJGL with Slick 2D.My Problem is that the countdown for the time for each level only work when you play the first time the level.If you win or loose in a level from the game i cancel the timer and you come after some time back into the main menu.But if you now want to play the level one more time the game is crahing. Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT1** :Now i want to know how can i create after caneling the first one timer a new instance from the timer with the same code.

This is the Error message i get:

```
Sat Sep 16 13:15:14 CEST 2017 ERROR:Timer already cancelled.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Unknown Source)
    at misc.Countdown.startTimer(Countdown.java:27)
    at menu.LevelMenu.update(LevelMenu.java:58)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.update(StateBasedGame.java:266)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Sat Sep 16 13:15:14 CEST 2017 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:669)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

And here is my countdown file:

```
package misc;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;

public class Countdown {

    public static int interval;
    static Timer timer1;
    private static volatile int runTimes = 0;


    public static void startTimer(int secs) {

        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        timer1 = new Timer();
        interval = secs;
        //System.out.println(secs);

        try{
        runTimes++;
        cancelTimerIfRunTwice();

        timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {         
                if(interval >= 1){
                    System.out.println(setInterval());
                } else {
                    timer1.cancel();
                    timer1.purge();

                    runTimes = 0;
                }
            }
        }, delay, period);

        } catch(Error e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } 

    public static void createTimer(Graphics g) {

        if(interval > 0){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("Rest Time: " + Integer.toString(interval), 830, 10);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("Rest Time: 0", 830, 10);
        }
    }

    private static final int setInterval() {
        if (interval <= 1){
            try{
                timer1.cancel();
                timer1.purge();
            } catch(Error e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        return --interval;
    }

    public static void cancelTimer() {
        try{
            timer1.cancel();
            timer1.purge();
        } catch(Error e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static void cancelTimerIfRunTwice() {
            if(runTimes >= 2) {
                try{
                    timer1.cancel();
                    timer1.purge();
            } catch(Error e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
         }
    }   
}
```

And here all refernced code from other class

From the Level Menu:

```
//Level1 button
        if((posX > 425 && posX < 490) && (posY > 410 && posY < 430)){
            //System.out.println("drauf");
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
                CreateMusicAndSound.soundMenuClick();
                Player.interation = 5;
                CreateMusicAndSound.bgmusic.stop();
                sbg.enterState(2);
                CreateMusicAndSound.musicFirstLevel();

                //create time for the level
                try{
                    Countdown.startTimer(30);       
                } catch(Error e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

From the Class for Win or loose from a level:

```
public static void Win(Graphics g, StateBasedGame sbg){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("You Win!", 400, 200);

        if(Player.GameOverSound){
            CreateMusicAndSound.soundYouWin();
            Player.GameOverSound = false;
        }

        Player.interation = 0;
        CreateMusicAndSound.bgmusicLevel.stop();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                sbg.enterState(0);

                //Setze den Player wieder auf anfangs posi
                Player.HitboxPlayer.setX(30);
                Player.HitboxPlayer.setY(420);

                //cancel den coundown timer
                try{
                    Countdown.cancelTimer();
                } catch(Error e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

                //Setze Points auf 0
                Player.points = 0;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    public static void Loose(Graphics g, StateBasedGame sbg){

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Game Over!", 400, 200);

        if(Player.GameOverSound){
            CreateMusicAndSound.soundGameOver();
            Player.GameOverSound = false;
            Player.HitboxPlayer.setX(30);
            Player.HitboxPlayer.setY(420);
        }

        Player.interation = 0;
        CreateMusicAndSound.bgmusicLevel.stop();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                sbg.enterState(0);

                //Setze den Player wieder auf anfangs posi
                Player.HitboxPlayer.setX(30);
                Player.HitboxPlayer.setY(420);

                //cancel den coundown timer
                try{
                    Countdown.cancelTimer();
                } catch(Error e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

                //Setze Points auf 0
                Player.points = 0;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

If you need some more information just write a comment i try to answer it so fast i can.
PS: Iam still student so foregive if some sentence or word cramatical unccorect. :D

Comment: It says right on the tin. "Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it." So no.

Comment: but when i create a new instance from this timer its posibile

Comment: Yes but the error you are getting is the runtime complaining that you're trying to schedule tasks on a timer you've already canceled. Your question asks whether you can do that. No. You can't do that. You need a new Timer.

Comment: okay than i change my question to "how to create a new instace from my timer "

Comment: You can edit your question. Take a look at [ask].